# websocket connection does not work

Tags: r, websocket

I seem to be in struggle with the websockets in R. I wanted to download the streaming data from the BitCoin exchange MtGox directly to R, but R cannot establish the connection.

The websocket specs are defined as:

- Host: **websocket.mtgox.com** or **socketio.mtgox.com**
- Port: **80** or **443 ( ssl )**
- Namespace: **/mtgox** (Including beginning slash)

url for more details: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming

and my code is:

```
require(websockets)
con = websocket("https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox",port=443)
```

and I always end up with an error:

```
> con = websocket("https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox",port=443)
Error in websocket("https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox", port = 443) : 
Connection error
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at the source code and manual here - https://github.com/rstudio/R-Websockets

The R Websocket library is out of date and not compliant with the WebSocket protocol as it stands.

So you'd need to fix the library or find an alternate one. Fixing the library isn't that hard depending on your ability. I managed to do it here -

https://github.com/zeenogee/R-Websockets

My one is (lazily) hard-coded to MtGox - use at own risk! You'd need to remove the current WebSocket library and install this one. Don't forget Your code is only doing the basic connection. There are a couple more steps to see actual data -

```
set_callback("receive", function(DATA,WS,HEADER) cat(rawToChar(DATA)), con)
service (con)
```

Comment: Wooow! Great! I will go through your code! However, there seems to be the problem with the package: the command `install_github("R-Websockets",username = "zeenogee")` ended up with a compilation error in libs folder: `** libs ERROR: compilation failed for package 'websockets' * removing 'C:/Users/Steef/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/websockets' Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: The way I applied it was - 1) Remove existing Websockets 2) Download mine. 3) Install mine locally. I'm on a Mac, so the procedure for a local install will be different. Details [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Windows-packages).  I'm using R version 3.0.0, so that might be something to watch for.  Even just looking at my commit on github might help. It'll highlight the changes I made.

Comment: I downloaded RTools and your package was successfully installed.

Comment: Great. It's pretty hacky, but hopefully gives you some idea :)

Comment: I need to post another question, as I dont happen to get the data flow. But at least I got a connection- many thanks again! :)

Comment: Yeah I did - it seems the websocket is silent, however, the link works if i put it in the browser :( I will make a new question to this topic.