# How to connect to websocket feed

Tags: r, api, websocket, feed

How does one connect to this websocket feed within `R`:

[wss://ws-feed.gdax.com](http://wss://ws-feed.gdax.com)

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530690/websocket-connection-does-not-work) post but I am unable to understand the workflow.

Is connecting to that websocket feed possible with `R`? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck on this one yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not... At least not with `R`....

Comment: Ok. I am going to give it a try sometime soon. I am currently working on a r package to connect to GDAX apis. Hopefully i will be done by year end. I am interested in getting real time feeds for my shiny app too but looks like Websockets is no longer maintained and its recommended to use `httpuv` but I haven't looked at it in detail. Would you be open to collaboration on websocket's project?

Comment: If I can contribute, let me know!

Comment: great! I am going to create a github page for gdax api as well as for web-sockets soon. Will come back and post the link here as soon as I am done. That ways you can check that out and we can take it from there.

Comment: https://github.com/DheerajAgarwal/rgdax

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can use [this](https://github.com/bradlindblad/GDAX_Trader.git) repository to help you get started -

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question.